# symfon2 rendreding choice from field entity in formtype

Tags: symfony

I wanted to display the existing value in the database in a selected field, however in my FormType I used entity field to display all possible value, and the field display for me the default value

this is my formType

```
  ->add(
            'way',
            'entity',
            array(
                'empty_value' => 'Selectionner la Sortie',
                'class' => 'MyBunde:Way',
                'property' => 'id',
                'multiple' => false,
                'error_bubbling' => true,
                'required' => true,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {

                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC');



                },

            )
        )
```

and in my AccountEntity I added a field $`$way`

```
 /**
 * @var String
 * @ORM\Column(name="way", type="integer")
 *
 */
private $way;
```

and this is what displayed in my twig
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxxdL.png)

so, when I clic on modify account, the value displayed should be 1 or 2, but what I see is the default value.

my controller is:

```
     public function modifyAction(User $user) {


        $wayf=$user->getAccount()->getWay();

        $form = $this->createForm(new UserModifyType(), $user);
        $form->get('account')->get('way')->setData( $wayf);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        //récupération de la requête du client
        $request = $this->getRequest();

        //on test si la requête est de type POST
        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $form->bind($request);
 ;
            if ($form->isValid()) {

                //mise à jour du compte
                $em->merge($user);


        }

        return $this->render('MyBundle:Account:modify.html.twig', array('user' => $user, 'form' => $form->createView(), 'errors' => $form->getErrors());
    }
```

How I can modify my code to see the value saved in the database in the selected field.

Thanks for help

Comment: It should work like this. Please show the controller.

Comment: $wayf=$user->getAccount()->getWay();
        $user->getAccount()->setWay($wayf);
        $form = $this->createForm(new UserModifyType(), $user);
        $form->get('account')->get('way')->setData( $wayf);

Comment: Edit your question and show the full controller action (formatted)

Comment: the code has been updated